# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. Apache POI Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to include Apache POI in my Android Project, but I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alexandra.kavb"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-3.14-20160307.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14-20160307.jar')
    compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

My Fail Log:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents
:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.68 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I already managed to track down the error to the xmlbeans.jar. But removing it results in the document creation not working.

Comment: I am guessing compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar') 
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14-20160307.jar') these two jars have common methods. Check inside code if same,then remove one of them

Comment: Why are you using JAR files? You can search Maven, for example. `compile 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:

1. Unzip the `jar` file. (Simply change `.jar` extension to `.zip`
2. This will remove the duplicate files.
3. Recreate the `jar` using `jar cf xmlbeans.jar -C (unzipped folder path) .` (Mind it, there is a dot in the end of command)
4. Use this regenerated `jar`

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked!
Can you maybe provide me with a link as to why the class is in there twice?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the dependency tree. You can see `xmlbeans` is a dependency of `poi:poi-ooxml-schemas` and `commons-codec` is a dependency of `poi`, and so you have duplicated those, thus the error.

```
+--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
+--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
+--- org.apache.poi:poi:3.14
|    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
+--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.14
|    +--- org.apache.poi:poi:3.14 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.14
|    |    \--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0
|    |         \--- stax:stax-api:1.0.1
|    \--- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:1.03
+--- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.14 (*)
\--- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0 (*)
```

If you just used Gradle to compile your dependencies, you wouldn't have that problem. You can search the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/) for all the dependencies you downloaded as JAR files.

```
ext {
    // Variables to keep libraries consistent
    supportLibVersion = '23.2.1'
    apachePOIVersion = '3.14'
    googlePlayServicesVersion = '8.4.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:${googlePlayServicesVersion}"
    compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile "org.apache.poi:poi:${apachePOIVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:${apachePOIVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:${apachePOIVersion}"
}
```

Note: I haven't actually built an app with these dependencies, so there may still be (different) errors.